# 3 tier architecture system

Tags: c#, java

our company has 7 factories those are located in different geographical areas and interconnected by leased line and all are in one domain in windows server. I have to develop a procurement system which will be used by users who are in each location. I can have one centralized database. I am thinking to design this using 3 tier architecture. currently the design in my mind is as below. (I haven't designed a system in 3-tier before). 1.install business layer in a server in each location. 2.install data access layer in head office in which the database in located. 3.install presentation layer in each users computer(can be swing application or web browser).

is this method worth? other questions are 1. what is the advantage of installing business layer in each locations server or install it in head office server is enough? 2.what are the technologies to passing messages between tiers in different locations. e.g: call a method "savePurchaseOreder(purchaseOrder)" in data access layer in head office from object in business layer in remote location

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you conflating "tier" with "geographical location"?  These really are distinct concepts.  It's very typical to build 3-tier or n-tier applications with all tiers other than the browser located geographically together in the same data center.  "Tiers" are about creating clean abstractions: you make a logical boundary between types of functionality, for example your "data persistence tier", "business logic tier", and "user interface tier".  Geography's not really involved with that.

Re your questions:

1. Business logic server in locations or in head office?  Likely depends on the bandwidth of your private WAN links.  You may achieve very fast response times for communication between browser clients and your business tier server by locating the business tier server geographically close to the users.  But if your WAN connection to your central database is slow, that won't matter too much.  Conversely, if you've got great WAN links between office locations and the head office, distributing business logic servers to the local offices won't make that much difference, and they might be easier to maintain if they were central.
2. Method of communication between distributed servers.  You could use RMI if that interests you, or simpler REST calls over TCP/IP.  REST with TCP/IP would most likely be easier for you to implement.

Hope this helps.

--Mark

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough bandwidth from the factories, you can deploy your business and data logic in your HQ and serve the application as web-based to the remote locations.

You may also want to consider an alternative approach where you deploy app servers to your factories to host the business/data logic and web servers to serve the presentation. Then you will need to sync the data in the database (i.e. replication) back to your HQ. This has higher maintenance but it does isolate failures to one factory should the system fail and also minimize the risk when upgrading the system.

A more advance approach would be to explore the cloud. Here's an article I wrote about deploying on-premise systems to the cloud.

http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.com/2014/01/layered-applications-and-windows-azure.html

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create one web application and host it in one of the offices? Other offices can simply use it through the web browser...

If security is a concern, I am sure your network team will be able to help you with Intranet setup or VPN connectivity, so that the website cannot be accessed by outside individuals.

Comment: Thanks Hirak for your suggession. Actually I want to get an experience in 3 tier architecture by developing this prject .

Comment: You can have the Client Tier,Middle Tier and Data Storage Tier in the same web application hosted from one location... Or do you absolutely need the tiers in separate physical locations?

Comment: not absolutely needed. I can decide better solution. but I want to know advantages of seperating domain layers between locations and how objects transferes between them.. thanks

Comment: If you are separating the layers between locations, you will need to use TCP or HTTP for communication purposes. This will cause a lot of network calls in your system... which will have a performance impact.

Comment: Thanks hirak for your comment